# Is it possible to update an item using list id instead of list title in the SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to update an item in a different list if any change event occurs on the source list item. I have different list id for different items on the source list that's the reason I wanted to update item using list id instead of list title. Is it possible to update an item using list id instead of list title in the SharePoint designer workflow 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You could call rest api `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listtitle')/items(itemid)` to update list item by 'Call HTTP web service' action.

You could refer [this thread](https://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/updating-list-items-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow-engine/) for sample.

Comment: He wants to ge list by id not title so ``/_api/web/lists(guid'listid')/items(itemid)``. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieving-lists-and-list-properties-with-rest